# React Router path renders multiple component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

i have following routes defined:

```
   <Route exact path="/dashboard/main" render={() => <Dashboard toggleModal={this.toggleModal} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu} />} />
   <Route exact path="/dashboard/channels/:id/:channelName/collaborators" render={(props) => <Collaborators {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
   <Route exact path="/dashboard/channels/:id/:channelName/:type" render={(props) => <VideoStats {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
   <Route path="/dashboard/edit_video" render={(props) => <EditVideo {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
   <Route path="/dashboard/account" render={(props) => <Account {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/> } />
   <Route path="/dashboard/socialMedia" render={(props) => <SocialMedia {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
   <Route path="/dashboard/media-library" render={(props) => <MediaLibrary {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
   <Route path="/dashboard/shares" render={(props) => <Shares {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
```

i am working on second and third route. 
now if path is : `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/channels/5ab09ca6d224c413423c2819/abc/LIVE_WEB`
`<VideoState/>` Component renders

But if path is:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/channels/5ab09ca6d224c413423c2819/abc/collaborators
```

then Both `<Collaborators/>` and `<VideoState/>` component renders.
i have tried all possible methods of removing and adding exact prop. like giving it to only one at a time and removing it from all of them. nothing works.
How do i avoid `<VideoState/>` component to render for the second path mention above.

Comment: Put those inside a `Switch`

Comment: will it matter if i swap 2nd line with 3rd line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Switch`.
It will render the first route that matches the `path` only.

```
 <Route exact path="/dashboard/main" render={() => <Dashboard toggleModal={this.toggleModal} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu} />} />
 <Switch>
   <Route path="/dashboard/channels/:id/:channelName/collaborators" render={(props) => <Collaborators {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
   <Route path="/dashboard/channels/:id/:channelName/:type" render={(props) => <VideoStats {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
 </Switch>
 <Route path="/dashboard/edit_video" render={(props) => <EditVideo {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
 <Route path="/dashboard/account" render={(props) => <Account {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/> } />
 <Route path="/dashboard/socialMedia" render={(props) => <SocialMedia {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
 <Route path="/dashboard/media-library" render={(props) => <MediaLibrary {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
 <Route path="/dashboard/shares" render={(props) => <Shares {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch

Comment: thanx it worked. Could you please explain what do you mean by "path only". i am new to react and react router and i am having so much difficulty understanding routing.

Comment: The `path` attribute that you provide to the `Route`. In its normal behavior `Router` renders all Routes that have their path matching to the current URL. But when you use a `Switch`, it will render only the first `Route` with path matching the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can get using another Component and  render condition base

```
const AnotheCompoent = (props) => <div>
{ props.match.params.type == 'collaborators' ?

<Collaborators {...props}/> : 

<VideoStats  {...props}/> }
</div>;



<Route exact path="/dashboard/channels/:id/:channelName/:type" render={(props) => <AnotheCompoent {...props} saveMatchForSidebarMenu={this.saveMatchForSidebarMenu}/>} />
```

Comment: collaborator is not supposed to be a :type param. it is hardcoded so that it is completely different path.

Comment: when you call with http://localhost:3000/dashboard/channels/5ab09ca6d224c413423c2819/abc/collaborators then you can check